# How do I solve the 'InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error' in my TensorFlow Deep Learning project?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am a beginner in the world of neural networks and I am doing a Deep Learning project with TensorFlow and I don't know how to solve this error. The delivery date is coming soon so your help would be very very appreciated :):

## CODE FRAGMENT:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def get_model(input_shape, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
    input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_sequence_len)(input)
    lstm = LSTM(rnn_units)(embedding)
    output = Dense(max_sequence_len, activation='softmax')(lstm) 
    model = Model(input,output)
    model.compile(loss = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer = Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model


from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode = 'max', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)


vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1 #total num of unique words
embedding_dim = 68
rnn_units = 128
batch_size = 16
epochs = 10
model = get_model(max_sequence_len, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units) 


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split = 0.1, callbacks=[callback])
```

## ERROR:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-4e8d160277a1> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split = 0.1, callbacks=[callback])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-30-6ae8be589bf4>", line 25, in <cell line: 25>
      history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split = 0.1, callbacks=[callback])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2078, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5660, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [16,30] and labels shape [480]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_10246]
```

I have already checked the correct shapes of inputs and outputs and different ways to write the fit function. I have tried a couple of other modifications but I am not able to find the core of the error.

Comment: Hi @Clara C, How many classes are there in your dataset you are trying to predict? You need to define the correct number of classes in the final output layer of the model. Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text) which might help you in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue while building a CNN model with LeNet architecture on the Cifar10 dataset, found out the problem was in the loss I defined. I changed mine from `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`. So maybe just use the categorical_crossentropy instead and see if it works.

```
model.compile(loss = CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer = Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```